# Brother scanner dcp1622we doesn't work , printer works just fine, ubuntu20.04

Tags: scanner

My network scanner doesn't work.

I installed the manufacturer deb. packages with bash command entered the device name which is 1610w and put in the ip of the printer. This is what I get :

```
dpkg -l | grep -i Brother
ii  brscan-skey                                0.3.1-2                             amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                    0.4.11-1                            amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  dcp1610wcupswrapper:i386                   3.0.1-1                             i386         Brother DCP-1610W CUPS wrapper driver
ii  dcp1610wlpr:i386                           3.0.1-1                             i386         Brother DCP-1610W LPR driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     6-1build1                           amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4.2-3                             amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

I also reinstalled the scanner driver with `dpkg -i --force-all` and
ran `brsaneconfig4`

```
brsaneconfig4 -q | grep dcp-1610w
* *dcp-1610w   [192.168.00x.xxx]  dcp-1610w
```

I have:

```
usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother4.so
usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1
usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1.0.7
```

Still, the simple scan message: "unable to connect to scanner"

Comment: when Document Scanner opens, use the down arrow to select a different printer. Look particularly for an `eSCL` option

Comment: there are no other printers, is just 1610w. that's it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put ]SOLVED] in the question title. Accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔ and turn it green ✅. This will mark your question as solved and help others.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem!!!

So for others i will detail it.
When i installed the package linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.3-1, with bash command, when i was asked for the device uri, i chose to input the ip address of the printer that was 192.168.002.009
for whatever reason it worked when i entered 192.168.2.9.
hopefully this is helpful for someone.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243205

Comment: IP addresses never have leading zeros. Trying to add `192.168.002.009` was a mistake. This is basic networking, and nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: See this for details: [Leading zeros in IPv4 address; is that a no-no by convention or standard?](https://superuser.com/questions/929153/leading-zeros-in-ipv4-address-is-that-a-no-no-by-convention-or-standard)